# filtering multiple values in place (excel)

Tags: excel

[image: Excel]

I can find alternatives to this question but I'm sure there's an answer.

The search bar here in the column filter drop down you can search for items to select.

If I have a number of unique id's, and I wanted to locate multiple of them, how could I type that in there?

Say id numbers [10,20,24,30,100]

edit:

I've tried the following syntax

10 - which sort of works

"10" - which works

[image]

"10" & "20" - doesn't

["10", "20"] - doesn't

"10", "20" - doesn't

I know there are other methods including the FILTER function as well as advanced filter. But seems like with multiple values in a single column, if I'm just checking all the boxes, I should be able to search for various values.

Comment: Whats wrong using the function to add the selected values to the existing search result? There is an option to do so right under "select all". You need to add the criteria one by one

Comment: I can, but I work 10k+ records and small batches. I figured there had to be some syntax that would allow such a search. I should say that the search:   10~20 does yield multiple results in combination but not 10 or 20 but larger numbers in combination. I know about the * and ? wildcards but none of those work in conjunction with the quotes (exact). I also can't find the search bar syntax documentation anywhere not even with MS

Comment: Well, I don't know that, but if VBA is an option, you could make use of the operator xlFilterValues with the array as criteria.
Or just use the advanced filter and a filter table.